# Set variable not displayed on windows command prompt. (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int Variable = 5;

    cout << Variable << endl; //any string that is requested to be called out by the system below will not appear.
}
```

So I compiled the program into an executable and run the executable, there were no errors , however when the variable was to be called on the command prompt, the value of it isn't displayed and any string after it isn't displayed either. Anything before `cout << Variable << endl;` seems to display. If I were to write a simple "hello world" program(no variables whatsoever) it would run normally displaying every string in the correct order.

Comment: Seems to work ok: https://ideone.com/Rb8KEg

Comment: What command prompt?!

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/Ttkxeg

This is your code, with some more additions, and it works perfectly!
Seems to me that your environment needs a `return` statement.

Try appending `return 0;` at the end of `main()`, else there is no error with the code!